# Delete row duplicates in a dataframe according to a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the dataframe:

```
df=data.frame(doc_id=c(1, 1, 2, 2), terms=c("virginia","bye","energy","energy"), freq=c(1,1,2,1))
```

i.e.

```
> df
  doc_id    terms freq
1      1 virginia    1
2      1      bye    1
3      2   energy    2
4      2   energy    1
```

I would like to delete the duplicates in column `doc_id` and `terms`; for example rows 3 and 4 have the same `doc_id` and `terms` fields. But the duplicates that I would like to hold should be those with maximum values in `freq` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `slice`.  After grouping by 'doc_id', 'terms', `slice` the row with `max` value of 'freq'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(doc_id, terms) %>%
    slice(which.max(freq))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   doc_id, terms [3]
#  doc_id terms     freq
#   <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>
#1      1 bye          1
#2      1 virginia     1
#3      2 energy       2
```

Or just `summarise` if there are only three columns

```
df %>% 
   group_by(doc_id, terms) %>%
   summarise(freq = max(freq))
```

Or with `arrange` and `distinct`

```
df %>%
   arrange(doc_id, terms, desc(freq)) %>%
   distinct(doc_id, terms, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

---

Or in `base R`, `order` the dataset first so that the `max` value of 'freq' will the first row for each group and then use `duplicated` to remove the duplicated rows

```
df1 <- df[with(df, order(doc_id, terms, -freq)),]
df1[!duplicated(df1[-3]),]
#  doc_id    terms freq
#2      1      bye    1
#1      1 virginia    1
#3      2   energy    2
```

Comment: Thank you! But it returns: Error: Column `terms` is unknown (with first solution)

Comment: @Mark your input dataset shows 'terms' as the column name and it is working for me

Comment: @Mark is it possible that you have a different column name in your original dataset as I couldn't reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option: using `subset` + `ave`

```
dfout <- subset(df,
                !!ave(freq,
                      doc_id,
                      terms,
                      FUN = function(x) seq_along(x)==which.max(x)))
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  doc_id    terms freq
1      1 virginia    1
2      1      bye    1
3      2   energy    2
```

---

Or a more compact version using `aggregate` (thanks to @akrun)

```
dfout <- aggregate(freq ~ ., df, FUN = max)
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  doc_id    terms freq
1      1      bye    1
2      2   energy    2
3      1 virginia    1
```

Comment: Another compact option is `aggregate(freq ~ ., df, FUN = max)`